# Procedure returning multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL on SQL Server, and got the AdventureWorks DB. I got around to writing a procedure, but somehow it returns an infinite amount of tables, where only the first table of them is correct.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SalesLT.Search
    @Name VARCHAR(40) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        Product.Name, ProductModel.Name AS ModelName, 
        ProductDescription.Description
    FROM 
        SalesLT.Product,  
        SalesLT.ProductModel,
        SalesLT.ProductDescription,
        SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription
    WHERE 
        SalesLT.Product.ProductModelID = SalesLT.ProductModel.ProductModelID 
        AND SalesLT.Product.ProductModelID = SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription.ProductModelID
        AND ProductModelProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID = SalesLT.ProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID
        AND Product.Name LIKE '%'+ISNULL(@Name,Product.Name)+'%'
END;

Execute SalesLT.Search
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

This is what I get when I run it.

Comment: Is it `MS SQL Server` or `MySQL`. Also it said `Query completed with errors` What is the error messages ? And what you have posted is it everything in your query window ? Is there anything else that you didn't post ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, MS SQL Server. The error is "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)."

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT a `GO` at the end of the stored procedure. Else you are doing a recursive stored procedure. The `Execute SalesLT.Search` become part of the stored procedure. The `GO` is a separator (refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SalesLT.Search
    @Name VARCHAR(40) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
Select Product.Name, ProductModel.Name AS ModelName, ProductDescription.Description
FROM SalesLT.Product, SalesLT.ProductModel,SalesLT.ProductDescription,SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription
WHERE SalesLT.Product.ProductModelID=SalesLT.ProductModel.ProductModelID 
AND SalesLT.Product.ProductModelID = SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription.ProductModelID
AND SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID=SalesLT.ProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID
AND Product.Name LIKE '%'+ISNULL(@Name,Product.Name)+'%'
END;

GO

Execute SalesLT.Search
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple. Thanks. Why does it return multiple false tables though? Because it is executing without parameters?

Comment: because without the `GO` separator,  the 'Execute SalesLT.Search' statement becomes part of the Stored Procedure. And the Stored Procedure becomes recursive. So when you execute it, it perform the select query and then follow by  'Execute SalesLT.Search'. So it becomes never-ending like a night-mare